# How to make containers scroll up and down and to also remove the spacing in between them

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently making boxcontainers in flutter that would serve as categories in providing content. The problem is I'm not an expert in flutter therefore, I'm having a concern here. I'm trying to figure out how you can make the containers scroll up and down the dart page. I'm also trying to figure out how I can remove the big space in between the containers, that way I could add more containers for content, and to also avoid having a renderflex. I would really appreciate it if someone is willing to help me.

This is currently my code in the dart page, let me know what changes I should make, or the proper code to input:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class AnxietyMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnxietyMainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnxietyMainPage> createState() => _AnxietyMainPageState();
}

class _AnxietyMainPageState extends State<AnxietyMainPage> {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
            Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(""),
                  SizedBox(height: 3,),
                ],
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                height: 42,
                width: 42,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_none,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              )
             ],
            ),

           ],
           ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("What symptoms are you feeling?", style: TextStyle(
                 fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                ),),
                TextButton(onPressed: (){},
                  child: Text("Show All"),
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 180,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                width: 320,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 42,
                          width: 42,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(""),
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                              )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child:Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Fast Heartbeat", style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                             ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 4,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(
                              Icons.bookmark_border,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 180,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 1,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                width: 320,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 42,
                          width: 42,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(""),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child:Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text("Hyperventilating", style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 4,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.bookmark_border,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
       ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
         child: Container(
           height: 64,
           decoration: BoxDecoration(),
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
             children: [
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.home_filled,
                      color: Colors.deepOrange,
                      size: 28,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 4,),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 3,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
               Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Icon(
                     Icons.web_asset_off_outlined,
                     color: Colors.grey,
                     size: 28,
                   ),
                   SizedBox(height: 4,),
                   CircleAvatar(
                     radius: 3,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                   )
                 ],
               ),
               Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Icon(
                   Icons.bookmark_border,
                   color: Colors.grey,
                   size: 28,
                   ),
                   SizedBox(height: 4,),
                   CircleAvatar(
                     radius: 3,
                     backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                   )
                 ],
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the containers to be scrollable and I also expect them to be close to each other, hence, removing the massive gap in between them.

Comment: each container scrollable or u need entire page scrollable?

Comment: I only want the containers to be scrollable actually not the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnxietyMainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnxietyMainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnxietyMainPage> createState() => _AnxietyMainPageState();
}

class _AnxietyMainPageState extends State<AnxietyMainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(""),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 3,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Container(
                        height: 42,
                        width: 42,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.notifications_none,
                            ),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                    "What symptoms are you feeling?",
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  )),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Show All"),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 1,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                  width: 320,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 42,
                            width: 42,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(""),
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Fast Heartbeat",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.bookmark_border,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 1,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                  width: 320,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 42,
                            width: 42,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: NetworkImage(""),
                                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Hyperventilating",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 4,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.bookmark_border,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 64,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.home_filled,
                    color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 3,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.web_asset_off_outlined,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 3,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.bookmark_border,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 3,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```